# Fails to connect to a local domain from Azure AD account

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, smb

So our our company moved to Azure, and migrated only part of the employees.
Now, a new employee, joined to the AAD is trying to connect to a local server on the network and I recieve the next error: "The specified server cannot perform the requested operation".

I read somthing about Azure AD Connect, which is being installed on the local server side to operate with the Azure domain.
Any other options?

Comment: Please check it may helpful : https://www.techinpost.com/the-specified-server-cannot-perform-the-requested-operation/

Answer (score 1):

•   As per your given explanation of the scenario, I can assume that you have permanently moved some of your AD users to Azure AD and then joined their devices to Azure AD. I am considering here that your local on-premises domain and your Azure AD domain are identical. Now, since your users are logging in with their official domain IDs on AAD joined devices, they won’t be able to access local on-premises servers/files shares or resources since they can’t authenticate these AAD users’ access to these resources through local AD. Since, as these servers/resources are domain joined to the local AD.

•   Thus, for these users to let them authenticate to local AD and provide them access to local servers, their IDs that are moved to Azure AD must be present in local AD. Therefore, you should sync your local AD IDs to your Azure AD tenant through Azure AD Connect application and should not delete them from local AD after successfully syncing them to AAD. Thus, after sync is successful through Azure AD Connect, your users IDs are available then on-premises local AD as well as Azure AD for them to authenticate to resources in their respective environments.

•   Also, you can ensure that your devices are joined to your local on-premises AD even after joining them to Azure AD. This will ensure that even after connecting to your office network, these devices are authenticated and recognized with your local AD and the requisite privileges/ permissions are applied to them. You can also connect to your local on-premises servers/resources through these devices over the VPN from public network once you configure your local on-premises inbound firewalls to allow connections through local AD authentication for the connecting users and devices.

Please find the below link for reference regarding the Azure AD Connect and configuration of hybrid Azure AD joined devices: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/cloud-governed-management-for-on-premises

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-sync-whatis